# Manipulating pixels in binary bitmap image with DataBufferByte

Tags: java, image

I'm having trouble accessing individual pixels in a BufferedImage. My image is binary, as in black or white only. This means that each byte of the image contains 8 pixels (1 bit per pixel).

To make sure that I'm indexing the image correctly, I wrote a quick test to set all the pixels to 1 (black):

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.File;

public class ImageTest {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        File input = new File("stripes.bmp");
        final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);
        System.out.println(image);

        byte[] byte_buffer = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

        final int width = image.getWidth(), height = image.getHeight();

        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                int byte_index = (i + j * width) / 8;
                int bit_index = (i + j * width) % 8;
                byte_buffer[byte_index] |= 1 << bit_index;
            }
        }

        ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", new File("stripes_out.bmp"));
    }
}
```

The input image, stripes.bmp looks like:
[image: stripes.bmp]

And the output is:
[image: stripes_out.bmp]

I expected the image to come out all black, but there are a few rows at the bottom that weren't modified. Apparently, I'm not reaching the end of the byte buffer.

Investigating further, it looks like there are some extra bytes in the array.

```
width = 810, height = 723
-> width * height / 8 = 73203
byte_buffer.length = 73746
```

Unfortunately, these 543 extra bytes aren't simply at the beginning, because skipping the first 543 bytes leaves a few rows unmodified at the beginning of the image.

What am I missing? How can I index the individual pixels correctly?

Comment: What is the size of the image? Have you tried through the Raster? It might be that there is a padding applied to keep the width a multiple of 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each image row in the byte buffer array is byte-aligned.  That means the "real" bit width of each row needs to be a multiple of 8.  In your image, each row is thus rounded up to 816 bits.  I assume the last 6 bits in each row are discarded.

```
    816 * 723 / 8 = 73746
```

So just round your width up to the nearest multiple of 8 and use that in your inner loop:

```
    final int width = image.getWidth(),
              height = image.getHeight(),
              rowBitWidth = ((width + 7) / 8) * 8;

    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            int byte_index = (i + j * rowBitWidth) / 8;
            int bit_index = (i + j * rowBitWidth) % 8;
            byte_buffer[byte_index] |= 1 << bit_index;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a place this is documented? I couldn't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find it documented anywhere either.  I just dumped the byte array to System.out (as `0`s and `1`s), looked for breaks in the pattern, and noticed extra bits every 800ish bits.  However, I just looked at the docs and noticed that the `BufferedImage` class has a `setRGB` method to set individual pixels.  Why not use this and pass in `0` for black and `0xFFFFFFFF` for white?

Comment: Nice detective work. The reason to avoid the getRGB and setRGB methods is that working with the DataBuffer is significantly faster (in my tests, at least 10x faster).

Comment: I read some more.  The `Raster` doc says "A SampleModel describes how samples of a Raster are stored in the primitive array elements of a DataBuffer."  So you're supposed to get the `SampleModel` from the `Raster` and use it to interpret the `DataBuffer`.  However it is the `SampleModel` subclasses that actually determine the data storage format.  It looks like all the subclasses have a `getScanlineStride` method which indicates how many byte array elements a line in the image is.  So you'll need to figure out what sample model you're working with and cast to that.